# Angular JS multi file upload request rejected in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, upload

We have a multi file upload requirement and the approach is below. I am sending all the requests as below and it works fine normally. However when tried with around 10 files with couple of them more than 10MB in Firefox only request gets rejected.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsaiH.png)

```
(function (i) {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', $scope.files[i]);
$http.post('yourUrl', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
}).then(function () {
    // ...
});
```

}(i);

```
  "Request error:" Object { data: null, status: 0, headers: Xc/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" } angular.min.js:103:49
e/<() angular.min.js:103
    .responseError() <myname>Service.js:59
        f/<() angular.min.js:112
            Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$eval() angular.min.js:126
                Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$digest() angular.min.js:123
                    Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$apply()
```

I spent lot of time but didnt get any solution.

Comment: not an answer but i would recommend ng-file-upload for this

Comment: Specific requirements in my application screen stops me from using ngUpload and write my own directive. Still didnt get any clue on this issue.